# Golang vips: How to render text with custom truetype font?

Tags: go, fonts, vips

When we want to render text an vips image, you do something like this with [vips_text](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/7.42/doc/html/libvips/libvips-create.html#vips-text):

```
    import "C"
    var textImage *C.VipsImage
    cText := C.CString("Some text")
    cFont := C.CString("Arial 12px")
    C.cgo_vips_text(&textImage, cText, cFont)
```

But here, `Arial 12px` is a fontconfig string name and assumes that the system has this font installed.

How do I let the program use a custom truetype font file, e.g., `Roboto.ttf`?

Trying

```
cFont := C.CString("Roboto.ttf")
```

probably won't work.

We could put the `Roboto.ttf` file in the system directory, for example, in Ubuntu you put the file in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`, but the code makes the assumption that this font exists, which is not a solution to write machine-independent program. So I wonder if there is a better way to do this so that we can ship the executables with the font file together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vips uses standard fontconfig font names, so you need to set up fontconfig to add your custom font to its search path.

[From the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) it looks like you can set the environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to point to your new font, then from go refer to that font as `Roboto 48pt` (for example).

It's easy to test from the command-line. Try:

```
$ fc-match "Roboto"
Roboto-Regular.ttf: "Roboto" "Regular"
$ vips text x2.png "hello" --font "Roboto 48px"
$ vips text x.png "hello" --font "Arial 48px"
$ eog x.png x2.png
```

And make sure you see two different images.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the env variable. I found this link: http://superuser.com/questions/365847/where-should-the-xdg-config-home-variable-be-defined. So the default `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` value is `$HOME/.config`, and that's where I should put the ttf file.